# unknown error of the declaration of a voxel output

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I am doing a point cloud joint with vs2013. The error happens at the declaration of the output object of the voxel filter.

```
// This is my test.
pcl::PointCloud< pcl::PointXYZRGBA>::Ptr JoinPointCloud(pcl::PointCloud< pcl::PointXYZRGBA>::Ptr oldpointclouds, dvo_framedata::FrameRGBD & newframe, Eigen::Affine3d & transform)
{
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>::Ptr newcloud = img2pcl(newframe);                   // Frame to point cloud.
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>::Ptr output(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>); // To save new point cloud.

    pcl::transformPointCloud(*newcloud, *output, transform); // Modified on 20170411.

    *oldpointclouds += *output;

    pcl::VoxelGrid<pcl::PointXYZRGBA> voxel; // Modified on 20170411.
    voxel.setLeafSize(0.01f, 0.01f, 0.01f);  // Unit for down sample point, which is 1cm here.
    voxel.setInputCloud(oldpointclouds);
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>::Ptr retout(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>);        // compiler ignored.
    voxel.filter(*retout);                  // Filter result is outputed to retout.

    std::cout << "-> PCL size: " << oldpointclouds->size() << std::endl;

    //output->clear();   // Added on 20170411.
    //newcloud->clear(); // Added on 20170411.
    return retout;
}
```

I have no idea why this line is ignored by the compiler. 
It does not give any information when mouse is on the variable.
[image]

Instead, it gives variable info if the one is finely declared. 
[image]

Another problem happens to breakpoints. I gave each line a breakpoint but it does not always goes forward when I press F5 which means that it goes back one breakpoint. That is really weird.
This attachment shows the breakpoint is actually from the next line after I press F5.
[image]

Comment: One reason for the debugger jumping back is compiler optimisations reordering things. Are you debugging a Release build, by any chance? Another reason is multithreading.

Comment: It is the release mode.

Comment: Yeah, debugging in release mode is a bit of a gamble, to be honest. There's all sorts of optimisations that could have been done. Best to do your debugging in a Debug build. There are probably some macros you can define to speed up debug builds if debugging them is taking way too long, but I don't have any specific suggestions for you in that regard.

Comment: Source-level debugging doesn't work well in release builds, even when you have symbols. The debugger is doing the best it can, but local objects/variables are often elided, which is why it can't show you the information about that particular variable. And as Rook said, optimization often leads to the reordering of instructions, compared to what you have in the source code, so the debugger is actually jumping back a line because that's how its symbols show that the C++ statements were translated to machine language.

Comment: You'll have better luck debugging release builds using address-level debugging, where you are looking at assembly-language listings instead of C++ source code listings, but it is considerably more difficult for the uninitiated. Do you have an especially good reason why you are debugging a release build, as opposed to a debug build? Is this something you're trying to do at a client site for deployed software? Maybe you can try inserting some logging output code, instead of using the visual debugger. Moreover, the question says there's an "error", but that doesn't appear to be what you describe.

Comment: Thank you all, guys. I'll try using debug build to know what happened. I use release version because of some weird problems of OpenCV, for example, gray window of imshow().

Comment: Thank you guys give me good experience. I am trying to do it from the very beginning with debug build.